# Why I can't see my process which is created fork function in linux top command

Tags: c, linux, fork

I have a C program which creates processes with fork() and prints pid of them with get_pid(). While this program is running, I use "top" command to see same processes, but I can't see them in there. Why? and how I can see my processes with "top" command?

Comment: Possibly your child process dies before `top` gets to register its existence; possibly your child isn't using enough resource to register on the first page of the processes that `top` shows.

Comment: run ps and grep the process and see if it is easier to find.

Answer (score 5):

top sorts according to a field, by default this is cpu time

your C program is probably too small and efficient to show up in the list

to see similar metrics to top but for a specific pid use ps, for example

```
ps -lp 12188
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm with @Vorsprung. You may also note that you can use `top` with a pid argument:

```
top -p PID
```